# Typesetting before TeX and computers?

Tags: tex-history

I was wondering how did mathematical and scientific books got typeset before TeX?
I see lots of papers from the 50's and 60's (on IEEE for example) running more than 20 pages long, with tons of complex equations and references. Yet they still look very neat and accurate (to some extent). How did it work back then?

Comment: Well, the **types** were **set** at that times at the printing company ;-)

Comment: With typesetting machines (Linotype or Monotype) and mathematics, to a certain extent, set by hand.

Comment: There is an image showing the process here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma/94891#94891

Comment: If you're interested in how math material used to be typeset, before the advent of TeX, I recommend you read David Wishart's 2003 article, "The Typesetting of Mathematics," in: *Type & Typography: Highlights from Matrix, the review for printers and bibliophiles*, Mark Beatty Publisher. Excerpts from this piece may be found in section 1.6, "Setting maths", of "A few notes on book design", which is part of the `memoir` class. Type `texdoc memguide` at a command prompt to get this document.

Comment: I think that Mico meant 'texdoc memdesign' rather than 'texdoc memguide'.

Comment: Related to a post in History of Science and Maths:[Writing Mathematical Symbols in 20th century](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/writing-mathematical-symbols-in-20th-century)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

actually, there *was* setting of math with computers before tex.  very specialized, and usually quite expensive.  in what follows, "symbol" is
used to mean either a letter of some alphabet, a digit, or some other shape.

there are several phases in the history of math composition:

- hand-set type -- anything before the late 1800s.
- monotype -- several patents from 1885-1890 covered this system and its
  basic operation for ordinary text.  the
  [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotype_System)
  covers this pretty well.  what it doesn't mention is the "4-line system"
  that was required for math.  this is described in [daniel rhatigan's m.a. thesis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fultrasparky.org%2Fschool%2Fpdf%2FRhatigan_Monotype_4-line_math.pdf&ei=j09PVcjwNo3HogT-xoCIBA&usg=AFQjCNFbKxP1_zjdpZyxYNTUcPWi9cXKyg&bvm=bv.92885102,d.cGU).
  this is the system used to compose the first editions of the first
  two volumes of knuth's "the art of computer programming", and it was
  the switch away from monotype that is the reason that tex exists today.
- "typewriter" composition.  actually, this is an oversimplification.
  the "direct type" methods were of two distinct kinds.  both were best
  used on machines with a carbon rather than an inked ribbon.

  - traditional one-symbol-per-key typewriters.  an "ordinary" typewriter
    has keys linked to type bars containing usually two symbols, with a
    "shift" key to change from lower to uppercase.  any symbol not on
    one of these type bars had to be added by another method, either by
    hand or by the use of a widget called a
    ["typit"](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60183a838?journalCode=ancham),
    a plastic device with a raised symbol at one end that could be stuck
    into a guide mounted on the typewriter where a key would impact the
    ribbon, and any key could be struck to impact the typit and transfer
    the image of *that* symbol to the ribbon and paper.  typits were
    used on machines with either proportional or fixed spacing.
  - a machine with interchangeable "fonts".  i know of two kinds used for
    direct manual input.

    the
    ["varityper"](http://site.xavier.edu/polt/typewriters/varityper.html),
    had a revolving drum onto which two semicylindrical fonts could be
    mounted, allowing both latin and greek (for example) to be available
    at the same time.  switching one font for another was reasonably fast,
    and the use of proportional spacing resulted in an appearance that was
    more refined than possible with a monospace typewriter, but not nearly
    the quality of real composition.

    the ibm selectric and "clones" used a "golf ball" mechanism.  these
    type units were easy to switch, although only one "font" (containing
    the same number of symbols as keys on the keyboard, times however
    many shift keys were provided) could be in use at one time.
- [photocomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototypesetting)
  was the next advance.  i know of one direct-input photocomposer used
  for math -- the photon 200.  a keyboard with several automobile-like
  shift levers controlled the input.  images of symbols were transparent
  shapes on a glass disk otherwise coated with black, like a photographic
  negative.  for "pi" symbols not on the disk, there was a "whirligig"
  with eight arms, onto each of which could be mounted a photographic
  negative of one symbol; jobs had to be carefully edited beforehand to
  make sure that no more than the eight available pi symbols would be
  needed, since changing the pi set in the middle of a job could run the
  risk of exposing the output medium, which would mean starting over.
  there was sufficient computer power in this machine to calculate line
  length and apply justification (in text), but for the most part, such
  decisions for math were manual, and required a highly skilled operator.

  for more automated photocomposition, input was keyed into some
  recording medium -- punched cards, paper tape, ocr forms, floppy disk,
  ... -- and input to the typesetting machine for output to photographic
  paper.  since photographic paper was messy and expensive, there were
  sometimes preliminary proof runs in which the input code was printed
  out on greenbar; not ideal, and accurate really only for text, but
  often less expensive than other alternatives.  (and patching paper
  tape was definitely an "interesting" undertaking.)

  output devices varied in how images were transferred to the photographic
  medium.

  - the photon 713 had a cylindrical drum into which were mounted
    35mm film strips, each with about the equivalent of what would fit on
    a selectric golf ball.  there were 16 of these fonts, so the available
    collection included roman, italic, bold, greek, and a reasonably
    comprehensive collection of math symbols.  the drum rotated at high
    speed, and the images were set by a carefully timed strobe while the
    disk assembly was advanced across the width of the paper by an
    absolutely gorgeous worm gear.
  - crt output was another possibility.  these devices were originally
    devised for use by newspapers, where speed was essential, and cost
    secondary.  the imaging process usually involved moving a crt beam
    along a predetermined path, turning it on and off as appropriate.
    the symbols in fonts were designed by hand, which involved defining
    the paths for the beam.  only certain directions were possible --
    vertical, horizontal, and at 45 degrees, but one of these was not
    permitted (i've forgotten which), so it was necessary to make sure
    that a symbol could be completed in a single, continuous path,
    avoiding the proscribed direction.
- there were a few small companies that developed math composition software
  before tex.  one was science typographers, whose program was used in-house
  at ams for about 20 years; a discussion of the [impact of tex on the
  suppliers of commercial math composition software](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb04-2/tb08letters.pdf) appeared in tugboat in 1983.
  (on rereading what i wrote then, i find that i haven't changed my mind
  about what makes tex a good choice for composition in general, and the
  most compelling argument against it has dissipated with advances in
  hardware technology.)
- one other essentially non-commercial typesetting system deserves
  mention -- [troff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff) -- which, with
  its companion `eqn` was created at bell labs and available on unix systems
  from the early 1970s, but which originally produced typeset output only
  on the cat typesetter, and was freely available only to unix sites.

this review has gone on long enough.  if anything significant is missing,
or any errors are noted, please let me know, and i'll try to remedy the
situation.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more, even if only for the link to the TUGboat article, which is instructively sobering for anyone who has been on one side or another of an argument about disruptive new technology. Also, it reminds us that TeX was new once. Also because it reminds us how quickly TeX stopped being new (I remember first hearing about it in 1987, as a thoroughly established Thing). Also because it shows how damn _weird_ the TeX logo looks when it's spaced incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks so much for this small lecture. Can we say that TeX splits the history of math typography in two parts: before TeX; after TeX?

Comment: Do you have a document which was typeset usin STI? I'd like to see its output.

Comment: There was also (at least) one *big* company that made mathematical typesetting software in the 1980s.   IBM mainframes had Script/VS, also known as Document Composition Facility which has an optional extension called the Script Mathematical Formula Formatter.  You started an equation with `.eq` and then used a series of keywords to layout the maths.  The target output was usually (enormous) laser printers.  I don't remember it being nearly as nice to use as TeX.

Comment: @Thruston -- i wasn't aware that dcf had a math extension.  the first computer installed at ams was an rca spectra 70, which was essentially an ibm 360 clone, but the first typesetting software used in-house was rca's page-2, which didn't have any math extensions (although we did occasionally "emulate" limited math formatting by explicit placement of the elements of a formula.  (believe me, it was tedious!)  thanks for the info.

Comment: Don't forget interchangeable daisy-wheels. I once had a typewriter which printed a line at a time to achieve full justification **and** could stop mid-line to allow the wheel to be changed. It could even cope with some multi-line stuff by defining/remembering horizontal position.

Comment: Barbara, thanks a lot for the interesting read. It was a pleasure to read the TUGboat article. I found it funny to see in hindsight that back then the experts expected LaTeX **not** to be used for math.

Comment: What a wonderful answer, Thanks a lot Barbara, especially for TUGboat link!

Comment: @Sigur -- the ams proceedings were set using the sti system from (don't remember exactly, but sometime in the 1960s) until the early 1980s.  all the content more than 5 years old is available in pdf form scanned from the original pages.  this link is for the [first issue of 1980](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-078-01/home.html)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I have a lot of old papers from Proc. AMS. I never imagined that they were produce with no TeX!! Looks too similar! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Apart from eqn, there was [PUB](http://www.nomodes.com/pub_manual.html) that predated TeX and which Knuth seems to have used a bit, but do you know anything about something called POX? Looking at the saildart archives it appears that Knuth's student John F. Reiser may have actually written his entire PhD thesis in POX (as early as March 1977, even before Knuth got the galley proofs of vol 2 that disappointed him and led to TeX), but I can find very little about POX anywhere, except a passing mention [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~learnest/spin/regrets.htm).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR -- i've heard of PUB, but know nothing useful about it.  but never heard of POX.  interesting.  i will have to keep a lookout for information.

Answer (score 29):

They were printed on linotype or monotype machines, which literally casted type. I had a close escape from the IBM golfball for my thesis:

[image]

As PhD students at the time we had to type our work on an IBM typewriter. This meant that when you got to equations you had to change the typewriter head, that looked like a golf ball, so don't complain about font changing commands in LaTeX. One advantage with this arrangement was that one became economical with words and more careful with spelling and writing.

Luckily TeX and LaTeX appeared and I moved onto using LaTeX when the LaserJet 1 appeared.

From YouTube 
[Commercial for IBM's Selectric Typewriter 1960's](https://youtu.be/vNUEUth7qjc)

Comment: Today was the first time I have seen this ball. On a YouTube video I could see how fast the ball turns. Amazing!

Comment: These typewriters were amazing and they had this beautiful whizzing noise. IBM also had these as terminals for mainframes and minicomputers. Edit my post please and add the link to the youtube video for others.

Comment: actually, very little math was set on linotype; monotype was *much* more capable, especially when setting fractions, sub-/superscripts, anything that required symbols "off the baseline".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the comment, I was always confused with the two.

Answer (score 14):

Many old books were typeset using typewriter with some symbols written by hand.

For example, Milnor's book *Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem* from 1965. Here is a preview of some part:

[image]

Also, changing the font they could type Greek letters.

[image]

Comment: or not so old documents like my thesis:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just for curiosity: is it online?

Comment: No, as I indicate, it was written with an IBM golfball typewriter, with large brackets done by hand (1985:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, so you didn't asked your students to scan it to you?! :)

Comment: I wouldn't call a book that was typeset using a typewriter "old". Old -- that's a term I would use for books printed before typewriters.

Comment: What are those symbols in the center of the type bar (PU2 and some monogram)?

Comment: @Random832, I have no idea. Maybe it is related to the company.

Comment: @Random832 -- several of them are the same, so i agree with Sigur that they are probably identifying the manufacturer.  my other guess was that they identified the position in which they were installed, but that seems impossible.

Answer (score 8):

In Germany, immediately before the arrival of LaTeX, a WYSIWYG program called SIGNUM (by Application System Heidelberg) on the Atari was quite popular for writing math and sciences. The program only died out when the supply of Atari computers ended---it had its fans despite being inferior to TeX in almost any aspect.

Comment: Signum is [still available from ASH](http://www.application-systems.de/signum/indexa.html), if Google Translate is to be trusted (my reading German is not great).  Admittedly you may have a hard time finding a working 680x0 Atari system to run it on, but there are plenty of emulators (e.g. the free [Hatari](http://hatari.tuxfamily.org/) and [PacifiST](http://www.atari.st/pacifist/)).

Comment: Approximately at the same time, there was also [ChiWriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChiWriter) - I've once submitted a paper prepared with its help.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy a secondhand hardcover copy of the classic

*The printing of mathematics;: Aids for authors and editors and rules for compositors and readers at the University Press, Oxford*

at

[http://www.amazon.com/The-printing-mathematics-compositors-University/dp/B0007JHCTQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007JHCTQ)

Here's the only Amazon review, from 2005.

> For a long time, this was the most thorough description in English of
>   math typesetting. Rather than giving long lists of rules, it is an
>   engagingly written essay. However, its concerns are not those of
>   today's typesetter. In every section, the authors stress the need to
>   consider the economics of each choice. That no longer matters, since
>   with computer typesetting, layout can be chosen purely on aesthetic
>   grounds. Read it for historical interest, but for practical guidance
>   get the  *Chicago Manual of Style*  or  *Mathematics into Type*.

In response to @Johannes_B : I recommend  this as a fun read if you can locate a copy. There would be no point in advertising an out of print hard to find book.

Comment: Can you extend your answer? Right now, this seems like pure advertisement.

Comment: this is one of the books listed by knuth in his published gibbs lecture, ['mathematical typography"](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-02/S0273-0979-1979-14598-1/), as being a significant influence on the design of tex.  another book along the same lines is by karel wick, "rules for typesetting mathematics".  (bibliography of the article is listed on the linked page; pdf of artlcle also linked from that page.)

Comment: Maybe not of interest to most, since it's in Swedish, but for those who can read it I must recommend the wonderful "Almqvist & Wiksells sättningsregler" by W. N. Lansburgh (1961) as well, being a manual for typesetters in science, with half of the book being used for typesetting of mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhere inbetween nostalgia and an answer.  If you look at many papers and pre-prints from the University of Chicago into the late 70's, they usually thank Fred Flowers for typing the manuscript.  There was a very expensive special purpose IBM machine for mathematical typing in the department.  It was Fred's full time job to type mathematics on it.

Comment: are any of these viewable on line, and can you provide a link?  (i'd like to pursue this.)

Comment: I'll look and see if I have any of my old pre-prints.  In the meantime, googling "fred flowers" chicago  typing turned this up-

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=eI36TEsH4N8C&pg=PP9&lpg=PP9&dq=%22fred+flowers%22+typing+chicago&source=bl&ots=Dm7F3M07jV&sig=KkSiwR6NyONeog0MvkszSlqSq9E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NJRSVY7OO8HJsAXGzoCYCA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22fred%20flowers%22%20typing%20chicago&f=false

Comment: i found several references like the one you linked, but no links to actual preprints.  if you find one, i'd be delighted if you could scan a representative page and add the image to your answer as an example.  i think the machine you may be referring to is the "selectric composer"; the output is quite recognizable.

Comment: I've looked and it seems that I was forced to get rid of all my old lecture notes when I moved.  It is possible that a friendly note to the math dept at UC may turn up photocopies or a link to where they can be found in the UC library system.