# Is this an originally typeset paper from 1946, or a new remake with TeX?

Tags: tex-history

Reading about the [history of mathematical typesetting before TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244082/typesetting-before-tex-and-computers), I found [an interesting article from Ivan Niven](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788) titled: "A SIMPLE PROOF THAT π IS IRRATIONAL" which is dated back to 1946 when there was no TeX (and probably [no computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) at all). The typesetting was great, and I was wondering if this is an originally typeset paper from 1946, or a new remake?

I have created a remake with plain TeX and also LaTeX, and the similarities between the plain TeX output and the original is astonishing! I am eager to know more about the similarities between the fonts and typesetting of the original document, and the output of plain TeX remake of this article. Compare these two for yourself:

---

[image: A 1946 article from Ivan Niven]

**Fig. 3: Original document**

---

[image: Remaking the original article with Plain TeX]

**Fig. 4: Remade with plain TeX**

---

**If this is from the old days, how they could achieve such a nice output?**

The article is published in:

Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society (Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.), Volume 53, Number 6 (1947), page 509, and it was first became available in Project Euclid in July 4th, 2007. In the [dedicated page for BAMS on Project Euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams) we read:

> The digitization and unrestricted availablity of the backfile of the
>   Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society (1891-1991) is made
>   possible with the generous support of the Gordon and Betty Moore
>   Foundation, the Mathematical Sciences Research Institute, and the
>   American Mathematical Society.

Compare the whole page of two documents. They are nearly identical! Even the hyphenation is mostly the same. They have slight differences in math spacing:

---

This is the code I used to remake the paper:

```
\magnification=\magstep1
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=5.0truein
\vsize=8.7truein
\font\footsc=cmcsc10 at 10truept
\font\footbf=cmbx10 at 10truept
\font\footrm=cmr10 at 10truept
\font\bigrm=cmr12 at 14pt
\font\smallbf=cmbx10 at 8truept
\parindent=0.15in
\pageno=509    

\centerline{\bigrm\bf A SIMPLE PROOF THAT $\pi$ IS IRRATIONAL}
\smallskip\smallskip

\centerline{\smallbf IVAN NIVEN}

\smallskip\smallskip

Let $\pi = a/b$, the quotient of positive integers. We define the
polynomials
$$\displayindent=0.3in\displaywidth=1.3in f(x)={x^n(a-bx)^n \over n!},$$
$$\displayindent=0.3in\displaywidth=3.3in F(x) = f(x) - f^{(2)}(x)+f^{(4)}(x)-\ldots+(-1)^nf^{(2n)}(x),$$
the positive integer $n$ being specified later. Since $n!f(x)$ has integral
coefficients and terms in $x$ of degree not less than $n$, $f(x)$ and its
derivatives $f^{(j)}(x)$ have integral values for $x=0$; also for $x=\pi=a/b$,
since $f(x)=f(a/b-x)$. By elementary calculus we have
$$\displayindent=0.01in\displaywidth=4.0in{d \over dx}\{F'(x) \sin x - F(x) \cos x\} = F''(x) \sin x + F(x) \sin x = f(x) \sin x$$
\noindent and
$$\int^\pi_0 f(x) \sin xdx = [F'(x) \sin x - F(x) \cos x]^\pi_0 = F(\pi) + F(0).\leqno(1)$$
Now $F(\pi)+F(0)$ is an {\it integer}, since $f^{(j)}(\pi)$ and $f^{(j)}(0)$ are integers. But
for $0<x<\pi$,
$$0 < f(x) \sin x < {\pi^n a^n \over n!},$$
so that the integral in (1) is {\it positive}, {\it but arbitrarily small} for $n$
sufficiently large. Thus (1) is false, and so is our assumption that $\pi$ is
rational.
\smallskip
{\footsc Purdue University}

\kern +10pt
\hrule width 1.0in
\kern +10pt

{\footrm Received by the editors November 26, 1946, and, in revised form, December 20, 1946.}

\bye
```

Comment: Monotype machine?

Comment: Seems so! I am looking at http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/Rhatigan_Monotype_4-line_math.pdf

Comment: Fonts are not embedded?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added my point about TeX history. I'm posting the output of my remake with plain TeX.

Comment: @cfr Check for yourself, you can download the article for free http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788

Comment: @Ho1 I did. But my viewer only gives me good evidence they are not embedded. To be sure, I'd need to copy it somewhere, switch to another application and run `pdffonts`.

Comment: The output shows that Times font (Bold, Roman, and Italic) are embedded, that should have nothing to do with the typesetting. They are usually embedded by the scanning software, in this case "ABBYY FineReader 8.0 Professional Edition".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added my quick remake with plain TeX. I think If this is an originally typeset paper, it can help better understanding the roots of TeX.

Comment: If I highlight the contents of the pdf file and copy-and-paste it to a plain-text file, it's evident that the original wasn't just scanned but fully OCR'd. It's also evident that the file is *based on a scan* rather than re-typeset via some variant of TeX. For instance, the greek character "`\pi` is rendered in plain-text in several different ways, e.g, `TT` and `7T`. In addition, other glyphs set in math italics also don't show up correctly in the plain-text file. This wouldn't happen if the pdf file were based on the output of a tex file, as opposed to an OCR'd version of a scan.

Comment: Good note! The PDF itself reports that is generated with "ABBYY FineReader 8.0 Professional Edition", which is a well known OCR software. But there are scanned papers who were originally typeset with TeX. So, let's be cautious.

Comment: see this paper of Knuths where he explains that the design of cm fontsand tex came about partly to get back to that era of AMS publication quality http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~millerpd/docs/501_Winter13/Knuth79.pdf

Comment: "If this is from the old days, how they could achieve such nice output?" [They could've done it by hand, of course :P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminated_manuscript#Gallery)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the paper. When I look at both titles, they are nearly identical for me! It's the math spacing that shows the difference: for example f(x). Even the hyphenation is the same for the first line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, It was a quick and somehow dirty remake! Could you please let this question remain open? I can edit and improve the question as much as it is needed.

Comment: @Ho1 The fonts are ***not*** embedded. I downloaded it and checked. The fonts you see are copies of Times which you currently have installed which is why the fonts *I* see are not the fonts *you* see although they are probably quite similar. (I get Times Liberation versions.) `pdffonts` shows the fonts which are used in the document. These are Times. But they are not embedded. Okular shows me the fonts used to display the PDF, which is based on the configured font substitutions for my system.

Comment: @Ho1 The question can always be reopened. In its current form, however, it has nothing to do with TeX. The document was not created with TeX and has not been reproduced with TeX. If you have a question about reproducing it with TeX yourself, that would be better asked as a new question focused on whatever specific problem you are having. (You can link here for background if that is helpful.)

Comment: @cfr I have actually recreated the document with LaTeX and plain TeX. The second screenshot is from the output of my remake. I am cleaning up the source to add it here.

Comment: TeXbook preface: `By preparing a manuscript in TeX format, you will be telling a computer exactly how the manuscript is to be transformed into pages whose typographic quality is comparable to that of the world’s finest printers;...`

Comment: For your TeX-based recreation, you should probably set `\pi` in bold in the title.

Comment: @Mico How to do that in text mode, in plain TeX? Also, it seems that the weight of the fonts in the original document is more that the weight of the bold text I have used. Suggestions?

Comment: Found a good solution for bold math in plain TeX: https://books.google.com/books?id=bXLDwmIJNkUC&pg=PA233

Comment: Sorry, I'm not nearly as competent in plain-TeX as I am in LaTeX. In particular, I can't offer a suggestion for getting a bold version of `\pi`. I'm afraid I'm also not much of a font expert, so I can't tell which font family you might want to use instead of Computer Modern to recreate the document.

Comment: @cfr I checked the original PDF in my PDF viewer, and also with the `pdffonts` utility, but do you think the dummy font (times) which the scanning software set is important? I think this IS a 1946 document, scanned recently, and have nothing to do with that dummy font. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Ho1 It is scanned. I guess it is probably an image with an OCR layer. I don't understand why it is only 48K in that case though. But there is something strange, I'm starting to think, about the PDFs produced by OCR these days. So probably you're right.

Comment: `pdfimages -list` command gives this: `.... color: gray ... enc: ccitt ... size: 40.3K` **ABBYY FineReader** is the finest OCR software which can be found these days. :-)

Comment: @Mico -- no, no, no!  maybe for "recreation", but in a properly edited ams journal, `\pi` would *never* be set bold in a title **unless for some mathematical reason it were also bold throughout the paper**.  (and this `\pi` is *not* bold in the title of the original.  checked it.  on paper.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for setting me straight. :-)

Comment: in 1947, the ams bulletin was typeset by the george banta printing company, menasha, wisconsin.  they were one of a handful of compositors specializing in technical composition of very high quality.  they would have used monotype machines, that being the only system in existence at that time that was capable of such work with relatively little additional handwork.

Comment: Section 1.6 of my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (try typing the command `texdoc memdesign` to read a copy on your screen) gives an example of how mathematics was typeset before the advent of TeX.

Comment: @Mico (and OP), perhaps it could be even more similar with one of fonts at the LaTeX font cataloge, http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html (I am not sure which one.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton make that an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in 1947, the ams bulletin was typeset by the george banta printing company, menasha, wisconsin. they were one of a handful of compositors specializing in technical composition of very high quality. they would have used monotype machines, that being the only system in existence at that time that was capable of such work with relatively little additional handwork.

the cited article, available from project euclid, is a scan from the original.
although the font is very similar to computer modern (in fact, it may very
well be the font on which computer modern is based -- monotype modern 8a),
there are characteristics that will positively identify it as *not* tex
output.

compare this integral from the scan

[image: integral from monotype page]

with this one produced by tex

[image: integral from tex output]

both the shape and the spacing are different.