# How was maths formatted before LaTeX?

Tags: typewriter, tex-history

I was curious and couldn't immediately find anything on Google or this site. Granted this question might be slightly off topic, but I feel that the people here would probably be able to give a better answer than most places.

When looking through old documents ( ~1910 or so) there is a lot of formatted maths of course, but there was no LaTeX, so I'm wondering how this was done.

Here are some examples of exam papers with typesetting pre-TeX, for some reason there was a 10 year period of monospace.

[image: 1961]
[image: 1962]
[image: 1972]
[image: 1973]

Comment: duplicate to this really although another one has more detail on monotype systems  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244082/typesetting-before-tex-and-computers?rq=1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah yes thanks - should I delete this post or wait for it to be closed? For what it's worth the other one didn't appear in a search or whilst I was writing this (maybe I searched poorly though)

Comment: and this from barbara http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255063/is-this-an-originally-typeset-paper-from-1946-or-a-new-remake-with-tex/276031#276031

Comment: I really reccomend the above two links.

Comment: Yes thankyou they're both what I was after, if you want me to delete let me know