# Use LaTeX to simulate old typewriter written texts

Tags: fonts, typography, typewriter, fun

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`typewriter`](https://ctan.org/pkg/typewriter)

I'm giving my students an old exam and barely remembered to change the date at the top. A colleague and I joked about how long we could reuse the same exam, and it made me wonder if I could use LaTeX to create an exam that looked like it was written in 1963 on a typewriter.

Here's what I'd like to see:

1. Typewriter font even in math mode. (Several ways to accomplish this; is there a "best" way?)
2. Slight inconsistencies in the printing of each letter. I attempt this below adapting code taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm). Each word has a random vertical shift, though I'd like to see it reduced to each letter having its own vertical shift. Other typewriter-like irregularities would be great.
3. It would be great if math-mode delimeters `\left(`, `\right}`, etc., can be created in a piece-meal fashion as they did in days of old.
4. Fraction bars, tops of square-root symbols -- any horizontal line, really -- is made up of a series of en-dashes that don't quite match up.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}% This is a document class providing more font size options
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[textwidth=7.5in,textheight=9.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

% thanks to Bruno Le Floch: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9331/4012
% and in his comments to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29458/4012
\usepackage[first=-1,last=1]{lcg}% you can play around with these values
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalrand}{\rand\global\cr@nd\cr@nd}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\randomvshift}[1]{\globalrand\raisebox{\value{rand}pt}{#1}}

%%% thanks to Martin Scharrer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11598/4012
\makeatletter
\def\typewriter#1{%
    \@typewriter#1 \@empty
}
\def\@typewriter#1 #2{%
   \randomvshift{#1}\space
   \ifx #2\@empty\else
    \expandafter\@typewriter
   \fi
   #2%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}\tt

\typewriter{Math 101 Fall 1963}

\begin{enumerate}
\item   \typewriter{$\frac{\texttt{d}}{\texttt{dx}}\texttt{(x)}^2$}

\item \typewriter{State the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did people typset math with a typewriter in 1963? I only know math texts from that time typed with a typewriter where all math symbols added carefully handwritten. So maybe all math should simulate handwritten math symbols (also with slight inconsistencies).

Comment: I'm a bit young for this (but don't often get to say that any more). But wouldn't you want the vertical offset to be consistent for each character?  Just checked somethign and it does seem so (in the example I found every "y" was above the baseline by about 0.1ex)

Comment: @student -- there did exist gadgets that provided extra "keys" with symbols to avoid (most) handwritten inclusions.  see the section on "typewriter" composition at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244126

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, it would be best if all "e's" had the same shift. I'd love that.

Comment: @student I used 1963 because it is well known around here that our school president graduated from here in 1963. But yes, that may be going back too far. I have a Springer text, copyright 1977, that is all typewriter-written.

Comment: I have a 19**9**7 data book on my desk that's typewritten with handwritten Greek letters.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122970/5763

Comment: Perhaps someone could provide a definition for mimeograph purple.  Only the stencil would come from the typewriter itself.

Comment: Related: [What's a good typewriter template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/whats-a-good-typewriter-template).

Comment: anyway to deactivate it and reactivate in one document? like switch on and off for certain parts?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

**This is now available as the `typewriter` package on ctan and texlive etc**

---

Improved version with some Greek and mathematics, and avoiding small numbers being written using 2e-5 notation into the pdf (and crashing the pdf reader)
This version assumes that the CM Unicode opentype fonts are available.

**2nd update now works with texlive 2016 stable release, and also a texlive 2015 updated to luatex 0.95** (Previous version only seemed to work in a texlive 2017 test release).

Slightly updated code available as a package here

https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/master/typewriter

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% luaotfload exlicitly loaded for latex formats before 2017/01/01
\usepackage{luaotfload}

% load cmuntt here not from lua (for everyone except me, it seems)
\font\cmuntt = cmuntt at 12pt \cmuntt
\edef\cmunttid{\fontid\cmuntt}


\expandafter\let\expandafter\%\csname @percentchar\endcsname
\directlua{
    local cbl = luatexbase.callback_descriptions('define_font')
    % print('\string\n======' .. cbl[1] .. '===\string\n')
    original_fontloader = luatexbase.remove_from_callback('define_font', cbl[1])
    luatexbase.add_to_callback(
        'define_font',
        function(name, size, i)
            if (name=='cmtt10x') then
                % this works in my dev version but for older setups
                % make sure cmuntt.otf has been loaded before we mess
                % up the font loader.
                % f = original_fontloader('cmuntt.otf',size)
                f = font.getfont(\cmunttid)
                f.name = 'cmtt10x'
                f.type = 'virtual'
                f.fonts = {{name = 'cmuntt', size = size}}
                for j, v in pairs(f.characters) do
                    local gr  = 0.4*math.random()
                    local gr2 = 0.4*math.random()
                    v.commands = {
                        {
                            'lua',
                            'r1 = 0.01*math.random(-10, 10)
                            pdf.print(string.format(
                                " q \%f \%f \%f \%f 0 0 cm ",
                                math.cos(r1), - math.sin(r1), 
                                math.sin(r1),   math.cos(r1)
                            ))'
                        },
                        {'special', 'pdf: ' .. gr2 .. ' g'},
                        {'push'},
                        {'right', math.random(-20000,20000)},
                        {'down', math.random(-20000,20000)},
                        {'char', j},
                        {'pop'},
                        {'lua', 'pdf.print(" Q ")'},
                        {'down', math.random(-20000,20000)},
                        {'special', 'pdf: ' .. gr .. ' g'},
                        {'char', j},
                        {'special', 'pdf: 0 g'}
                    }
                end  % end of for
                return f
            else
                return original_fontloader(name, size, i)
            end  % end of if
        end,  % end of function
        'define font'
    )  % end of add_to_callback
}

\def\sqrt#1{^^^^221a\overline{#1}}


\begin{document}
$\relax$

\font\myfont= cmtt10x at 12pt \myfont
\font\myfonts= cmtt10x at 7pt
\let\selectfont\relax

\textfont0=\myfont
\scriptfont0=\myfonts 
\scriptscriptfont0=\myfonts 
\textfont1=\myfont
\textfont2=\myfont
\textfont3=\myfont

\section{Introduction}

ABCD one two theee four five

TTTTTTTooooooWWWWW

\begin{enumerate}
\item red yellow blue green
\item black blue purple
\end{enumerate}

[some greek text θ]

and in math $x^2-\cos θ$


\[\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+y}}\right)\]

\raggedleft
typeset by egreg design services
\end{document}
```

---

Original:

[image]

This introduces randomness on every use of each letter of the document. It requires luatex. (math is possible but not yet)

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua {
    local cbl = luatexbase.callback_descriptions('define_font')
    original_fontloader = luatexbase.remove_from_callback('define_font', cbl[1])
    luatexbase.add_to_callback(
        'define_font',
        function(name, size, i)
            if (name=='cmtt10x') then
                f = font.read_tfm('cmtt10', size)
                f.name = 'cmtt10x'
                f.type = 'virtual'
                f.fonts = {{name = 'cmtt10', size = size}}
                for j, v in pairs(f.characters) do
                    local gr  = 0.4*math.random()
                    local gr2 = 0.4*math.random()
                    v.commands = {
                        {'lua',
                         '
                            r1 = 0.05+0.1*math.random()
                            pdf.print
                            (" q "
                                .. math.cos(r1) .. " "
                                .. - math.sin(r1) .. " "
                                .. math.sin(r1) .. " "
                                .. math.cos(r1) .. " 0 0 "
                                .. " cm "
                            )
                          '
                        },
                        {'special', 'pdf: ' .. gr2 .. ' g'},
                        {'push'},
                        {'right', math.random(-30000,30000)},
                        {'down', math.random(-30000,30000)},
                        {'char', j},
                        {'pop'},
                        {'lua', 'pdf.print(" Q ")'},
                        {'down', math.random(-30000,30000)},
                        {'special', 'pdf: ' .. gr .. ' g'},
                        {'char', j},
                        {'special','pdf: 0 g'}
                    }
                end  % end of for
                return f
            else
                return original_fontloader(name, size, i)
            end  % end of if
        end,  % end of function
        'define font'
    )
}


\begin{document}

\font\myfont= cmtt10x at 12pt \myfont
\let\selectfont\relax

\section{Introduction}

ABCD one two theee four five

TTTTTTTooooooWWWWW

\begin{enumerate}
\item red yellow blue green
\item black blue purple
\end{enumerate}


\raggedleft
typeset by egreg design services
\end{document}
```

This emulates a *really poor* typewriter with dodgy print hammers that wobble and move around as each key is hit:-)

Comment: My ”tesi di laurea“ was typed with a *much* better typewriter.

Comment: Epic indentation is epic.

Comment: Man, had I been given an exam subject like this, I would have quit math. Oh wait, I did.

Comment: @egreg math added for you

Comment: MY THESIS WILL USE THIS.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is there a way to control how bad the typewriter is? I mean, **egreg's design services** has a really bad old typewriter, poorly maintained. But maybe **carlisle's design services** has an old one too, but a good one. `;)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli yes see the arbitrary scale factors on the random number gen eg the rotation of one of the over-printed characters is `r1 = 0.01*math.random(-10,10)` make that 0.001* and you wil have a tenth of the angle in each case, while debugging I had it as 1* just to check something is happening (but you can't read it all then) similarly the two random numbers used for gray colour are set to arbitrary values. 0 is black 1 is white so you can limit the range and make that range blacker or whiter

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli my thesis (1985) was set on an IBM golfball typewriter so had no wobbly print hammers at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- are you saying the golf ball wasn't wobbly?

Comment: How to compile this? I tried it with lualtex, but it resulted in ! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: attempt to concatenate field '?' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.

Comment: Sigh - looks great but I also can't get to run on my Windows machine. I get `\myfont=cmtt10x at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.` Thought that I had the computer modern fonts installed, but I also don't know how to confirm. Any help out there? (Running `LuaTeX Version 0.95.0`.)

Comment: Absolutely beautiful -- except superscript size needs to be the same as the text size.

Comment: @ScottSeidman see comment above, I had (access to) a fancy typewriter:-)

Comment: Got it!  How about erasure smears and white-out outlines?  I had the fancy white-out film that you typed on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried it. Got different error this time: `Font cmuntt.otf not found.' Looked online for a copy of this font, placed `cmuntt.otf` in the same directory as my file. Now I get the old `Font \myfont=cmtt10x at 12pt not loadable` again. I did back up into my log file and found I also have the comment `attempt to index global 'f' (a nil value). <to be read again>` error.

Comment: Not here - but my TL2015 apparently has luatex v0.80.0

Comment: @GregH answer updated with a version tested with luatex 0.95 as in public texlive 2016 .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, will do though I'm away from that machine for the weekend and can't remember what versions I've got on my personal machines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I was able to typeset your top example with TL 2016 and current updates. Nice, typically devious, work. To my eye the minus sign and the horizontal rules for the square root look a little thin, though. :)

Comment: @musarithmia fix for that on the way:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The update works for me, marked this as the "correct" answer, though would enjoy other's take, too. FWIW, commands such as `\pi` don't display for me (no errors, no blank space either) but I can copy/paste a pi symbol (from MS Word). This worked too for a theta, though capital Sigma for summations didn't render; `\sum` renders as a capital P. Overall: Well done & thanks!

Comment: @GregH `\sum` will work if you get the version from github as will all the greek commands `\muppi` from unicode-math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can one add characters that are affected by your code? I defined an "underline leader" to mimic underlining by repeatedly pressing "`_`", via `\def\underlineleader{\leaders\hbox to .35em{\hss\_\hss}\hfill\ }`. However, the lines are "too nice"; they are typeset regularly, rather than with the "typewriter." It would be fun to typeset all vertical & horizontal rules in a table in a similar fashion.

Comment: @GregH I'll add some more bits to the typewriter package on github. use `\string_` not `\_` see the version of `\overline` I put there already

Comment: @GregH package in github has support for tables and usual commands such as `\alpha` [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaFh3.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The tables are perfect. (I wonder if Knuth is chuckling "I created TeX to get away from this very look...")

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried the version from github which worked very well. My lualatex is 0.80.0.

Comment: @Julia thanks for letting me know:-)

Comment: The couple of minor tweaks that I would suggest, (remembering back to when it wasn't unusual to see internal exams prepared this way), would be that where Greek letters were made with over-typing, e.g. Theta would be 0<bs>- there was often variability of the (miss)alignment of the two components both vertically and horizontally. Bold was often attempted with double typing. Also some typewriters had a) some damaged hammers and poor paper alignment/retention. I love the effort that has gone into this!

Comment: Is there a way to simulate typewriter exponents that are full-sized characters typed on a line above?

Comment: @Evpok probably:-) (not today though)

Comment: I even discovered a typo.

Comment: Strangely, I can't compile a simple file with `LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)` on Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed the oft versions of the fonts, run `fc-cache -f -v` and I still get the error `Font \cmuntt=file:cmuntt.otf at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \font\cmuntt = file:cmuntt.otf at 12pt \cmuntt`. Suggestions as to what I should try?

Comment: @thymaro cmuntt.otf is the typewriter font from the Computer Modern Unicode collection. You need to install cmunicode in texlive or miktex, whichever you use.

Comment: hmm, the error persists, even after rebuilding formats and updating the fmdb. LuaLaTeX says the error is on line 28 in typewriter.sty `\font\cmuntt = file:cmuntt.otf at 12pt \cmuntt`

Comment: @thymaro it is nothing to do with the format, do you have cmuntt.otf installed? If you don't have it, luatex can not use it, it should be at a location such as `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmuntt.otf`

Comment: that's exactly where I found it.

Comment: sorry can't really help (and comments under this question not a good format) make a simple luatex document using cmuntt.otf either directly or via fontspec (no need for the typewriter package) and if it doesn't load the font you could ask a new question about that with a log file etc that people can debug

Comment: I've taken the liberty of assigning better pretty-printing to the Lua code block. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico That inserts code window breaks though

Comment: @percusse - What breaks?

Comment: @Mico Now the code is broken into 3 pieces

Comment: @Mico I think I'll revert, as percusse says this means you can't copy the text in one operation,

Comment: Is possible to introduce (micro)-randomness in common Computer Modern family? Small variations in serif for example and similar. I am not a typographer, but according to some university course on math typsetting, there is goood reason for using these imperfections. Unfortunately, I have never found any article about the topic. Are there any?

Comment: @JanFilip not yet but as support for the (new) opentype variable font features start to appear, then perhaps.

Comment: Is there a way how to get it when its released? I mean if there is some channel which I have to follow to get news about it?

Comment: @JanFilip you say "it" as if there was some specific thing, I just meant that someone could perhaps write something, so the same places as any tex news: here, the ctan-announce mailing list, etc

Comment: I am not used to LuaTex, but I love this font.  Is it easy to port to / use within xetex?

Comment: @Tim no not possible at all, sorry, this is using Lua to programmatically distort the characters on each use

Comment: Thanks for your package! However, I have downloaded the newest version and `\in`, `\sum`, `\subseteq`, `\oplus` seems not to work. Would you do me a favor to add a minimal working example to these symbols?