# Writing a tex file in \texttt font

Tags: font-encodings

I am trying to write a tex file in Kile with font `\textt`.

This font looks like following typing in a book [Number fields-Marcus](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kmnlBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=number%20fields%20marcus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7lM_V9onRAhXEsY8KHTniBCsQ6wEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=number%20fields%20marcus&f=false).

But when after `\begin{document}` I wrote `\tt` or `\texttt`, the text was exceeding line in the pdf file; in other words, it was showing some warning.

How can I settle the `\texttt` font in Kile?

Comment: This book was written on a [typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter).  Today we are able to do fine typesetting using a desktop computer, so there is no need to fake the very bad typography produced by a typewriter.

Comment: If you nevertheless want to do this, use `\ttfamily\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke you mean fine luatex [settings like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts/344272#344272)?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[ 
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  FakeStretch=0.85, 
]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}%% only demo

\renewcommand\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\AtBeginDocument{%  for justified typewriter
  \fontdimen3\font=3pt  
  \fontdimen4\font=1pt 
}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My TeX installation didn't recognize the DejaVu Sans Mono. It did with courier.