# Combining mathcal and mathbb with thin lines

Tags: math-mode, alphabet

I am actually looking for tweak to this post
[Composition of \mathbb and \mathcal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415675/composition-of-mathbb-and-mathcal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In particular would it be possible to get the same letters but with thin lines instead of think lines featured in the nice answer of this post?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?  (pdflatex only)

To summarize what is being done, I am using pdf specials (pdflatex only) to print the glyph core and outline as two separate colors `\fillcolor` defining the core color and `\bordercolor` defining the outline color.  The "thickness" (a scalar value) of the outline is defined by `\thickness` and, in several of the cases, I overlay two glyphs atop each other with a slight kerning offset, where the `\kern` is specified in the stack.

This first example is not overlaid with two glyphs, but merely a simple pdf special setting the letter core white and the outline black, with a chosen `\thickness` of `.1`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathcalbb[2][1]{\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW
\begin{document}
$\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb{B}\mathcalbb{C}\mathcalbb{D}\mathcalbb{E}\mathcalbb{F}
\mathcalbb{G}\mathcalbb{H}\mathcalbb{I}\mathcalbb{J}\mathcalbb{K}\mathcalbb{L}
\mathcalbb{M}$

$\mathcalbb{N}\mathcalbb{O}\mathcalbb{P}\mathcalbb{Q}\mathcalbb{R}
\mathcalbb{S}\mathcalbb{T}\mathcalbb{U}\mathcalbb{V}\mathcalbb{W}\mathcalbb{X}
\mathcalbb{Y}\mathcalbb{Z}
$

$\mathcalbb[.8]{A}\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb[1.2]{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or maybe like this, which includes a kerned offset overlay:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathcalbb[2][1]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{\kern.3pt\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW
\begin{document}
$\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb{B}\mathcalbb{C}\mathcalbb{D}\mathcalbb{E}\mathcalbb{F}
\mathcalbb{G}\mathcalbb{H}\mathcalbb{I}\mathcalbb{J}\mathcalbb{K}\mathcalbb{L}
\mathcalbb{M}$

$\mathcalbb{N}\mathcalbb{O}\mathcalbb{P}\mathcalbb{Q}\mathcalbb{R}
\mathcalbb{S}\mathcalbb{T}\mathcalbb{U}\mathcalbb{V}\mathcalbb{W}\mathcalbb{X}
\mathcalbb{Y}\mathcalbb{Z}
$

$\mathcalbb[.8]{A}\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb[1.2]{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or, lastly,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathcalbb[2][1]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\def\thickness{.15}\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{\kern.1pt\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW
\begin{document}
$\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb{B}\mathcalbb{C}\mathcalbb{D}\mathcalbb{E}\mathcalbb{F}
\mathcalbb{G}\mathcalbb{H}\mathcalbb{I}\mathcalbb{J}\mathcalbb{K}\mathcalbb{L}
\mathcalbb{M}$

$\mathcalbb{N}\mathcalbb{O}\mathcalbb{P}\mathcalbb{Q}\mathcalbb{R}
\mathcalbb{S}\mathcalbb{T}\mathcalbb{U}\mathcalbb{V}\mathcalbb{W}\mathcalbb{X}
\mathcalbb{Y}\mathcalbb{Z}
$

$\mathcalbb[.8]{A}\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb[1.2]{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

In this gratuitous example, I reverse the colors (border white, fill black) for the thicker  of the two stacked glyphs.  By increasing the thickness of the white border, I reduce the apparent thickness of the black core.  However, the offset overlay is done in the other fashion, with a thin black border.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathcalbb[2][1]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\bordercolor{black}%
\fillcolor{white}%
\def\thickness{.2}\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{\kern.15pt\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\bordercolor{white}
\fillcolor{black}
\def\thickness{.25}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW
\begin{document}
$\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb{B}\mathcalbb{C}\mathcalbb{D}\mathcalbb{E}\mathcalbb{F}
\mathcalbb{G}\mathcalbb{H}\mathcalbb{I}\mathcalbb{J}\mathcalbb{K}\mathcalbb{L}
\mathcalbb{M}$

$\mathcalbb{N}\mathcalbb{O}\mathcalbb{P}\mathcalbb{Q}\mathcalbb{R}
\mathcalbb{S}\mathcalbb{T}\mathcalbb{U}\mathcalbb{V}\mathcalbb{W}\mathcalbb{X}
\mathcalbb{Y}\mathcalbb{Z}
$

$\mathcalbb[.8]{A}\mathcalbb{A}\mathcalbb[1.2]{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! thanks. Could you maybe highlight which command I need to change to vary the thickness?

Comment: @AnneO'Nyme `\def\thickness{.1}` defines the line thickness.  In the two latter examples, two offset copies are overlaid.  the horizontal offset is defined by the `\kern.15pt` inside the stack.