\mathcal combined with \mathbb and colors
This answer proposes a nice way to combine \mathcal and \mathbb. My question is how to make it work within a color group.
Currently, the following code:
{\color{red} Some text before. $\mathcalbb{A}$. Some text after.}

produces the following result:

However, I would like the $\mathcalbb{A}$ to be red as well.
Additionally, I would like the definition of the \mathcalbb command, which combines \mathcal and \mathbb, to be “uniform” in terms of color. Specifically, I want to create a (universal if I may say) command that works with any color, not only with red or any other fixed color, and automatically changes the color of the symbols according to the group’s color without requiring the color to be passed as a parameter. In other words, I don't want to have different commands for different colors, and I don't want to specify the color of the symbol manually each time I need to use it inside a color group.

Assuming your code loads the xcolor package, have you tried $\mathcolor{red}{\mathcalbb{A}}$?

@Mico I've just tried and it didn't work. The result is the same.

The posting you've provided a link to contains the following instructions:
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW

Change the arguments black and white to whatever you want them to be. Say,
\bordercolor{red}
\fillcolor{yellow}

If the border color of your choice is a bit on the pale side, you may also want to run
\def\thickness{.12}


Addendum: To assure that the color of \mathcalbb{<x>} is the same as of its immediate surroundings, I suggest you first set up a macro called, say, \mycolor as follows:
\newcommand\mycolor[2][red]{% feel free to choose another default group color
   \begingroup
   \bordercolor{#1}
   \color{#1}#2
   \endgroup}

An MWE (minimum working example) that implements this idea:

\documentclass{article}

% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493517/5001
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathcalbb[2][1]{\outline{$\mathcal{#2}$}}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.12}% TO CHANGE THICKNESS OF SHADOW

%% new:
\newcommand\mycolor[2][red]{% or some other default color
   \begingroup
   \bordercolor{#1}
   \color{#1}#2
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}

$\mathcalbb{A}$ % black

\mycolor{Some text before. $\mathcalbb{A}$. Some text after.}

\mycolor[blue]{Some text before. $\mathcalbb{A}$. Some text after.}

$\mathcalbb{A}$ % check that we're back to black

\end{document}


"...automatically changes the color of the symbols according to the group’s color without requiring the color to be passed as a parameter." By this I meant that I don't want to specify the color manually each time I need to use \mathcalbb inside a color group. I will try to make the formulation clearer.

@NikitaSafonkin - Please see the addendum I posted.
