# document with math in typewriter text

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

I am trying to emulate old mathematics course notes from the 90's, written on typewriter. I am not looking to match the typeface exactly, but rather the general style of the document.

I have tried loading various typewriter and monospace fonts with XeTeX, but none seem to provide a usably complete set of maths symbols (operators, upright uppercase greek, ...). Here is the gist of what I tried:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmathfont{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

More specifically, I have tried loading essentially every typewriter or monospace font I could find. I have also tried setting all font variants manually in the `\setxxxxfont` call. Nothing seems to produce a usable typewritten maths alphabet. Everything seems to produce a warning that the "Math" script is missing in the font.

Can someone provide a font selection (for pdfLaTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, ...) that will result in the entire document, including almost all maths, being set in a typewriter or monospace font?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344272/1090

Comment: I had seen that, but it goes a bit too far in items of emulation :)

Comment: sure but you can take the math  settings and leave out the overprinting and random rotation silliness

Comment: But does that not still replace things like `\sqrt` and `\pmatrix` with single character equivalents as would be found on an actual typewriter? I would like to keep the TeX math typesetting as much as possible intact, only in a typewriter font.

Comment: just edit it to put `\mathtt{...}` around the maths?