# Is there anyone that knows what this font could be?

Tags: fonts

I'm asking what this font is and whether this is a TrueType/OpenType font that works normally with non-latex software (preferrably) or an in-built math font in LaTeX. [image]

Comment: This was produced with a typewriter..

Comment: Well I don't exactly have access to a pdf file and I have tried most methods listed in the link u supplied but thank for you input and I'll keep on searching I suppose

Comment: Does this being produced with a typewriter imply that I won't be able to find the font? If so then that'd be pretty unfortunate

Comment: For instance, the vertical position of the letter `e` varies a bit, so it is a bit reminiscent of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344272/194703.

Comment: Maybe a typewriter but maybe an impact printer, with a math print-ball or daisy wheel.

Comment: Diablos did a physical two-pass, swapping daisy wheels (http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/diablo.html), so we know where TeX got the idea :). Unrelated - no-one makes the ink ribbons anymore.