# How to emulate "typewriter" style?

Tags: equations, packages, typography, typewriter

[Not sure how to word this question exactly, please let me know if it is a duplicate.]

Many older scientific papers are set completely in "typewriter" style. Here is an equation that was set using the IBM Selectric typewriter:

> [image]
>
> (taken from http://www.practicallyefficient.com/2017/10/13/from-boiling-lead-and-black-art.html)

Superscripts and subscripts are the same size as ordinary characters, as is the summation symbol. Is there a way to reproduce this in LaTeX? I imagine that a way to do this might be to (1) somehow enforce that all glyphs are the "normal" size and (2) use a typeface with monospaced math glyphs.

I'm aware of the `typewriter` package, although it doesn't completely solve my problem, since it seems to change the size of subscripts and superscripts.

Any help or any suggestions on how to improve the wording of my question would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts/344272#344272

Comment: the package does change subscripts by default (in fact there were comments that it should not, it depends on how fancy a typewriter you are emulating) there are some superscripts in the image on that answer, that is easily arranged.

Comment: you say the package is not right as it does *not* change the size of subscripts, did you mean to say the opposite?

Comment: From the image on your answer it seems like the superscript 2 is smaller, though. But I'll try out your package, thank you!

Comment: yes it is smaller by default (but doesn't need to be) but your question says that the package is unsuitable as it does not change the size. I think you meant to say the opposite, that it is unsuitable because it does change the size?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you for catching that, I meant to say the opposite. Sorry for the confusion. How would I make superscripts the regular size using your package?

Comment: hmm I think after begin document you can do \scriptfont0=\textfont0 \scriptscriptfont0=\textfont0

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'll try that! Thank you

Comment: I ought to make the subcript factor a parameter so you could just set it to 1 if you wanted same-size subscripts, I may do that if I ever update the package.