# Grammar check in TexWork

Tags: texworks, grammar

Is there any good grammar check plugin/program in TexWorks? Or is there any at all? I am looking for English language checker. 
Or maybe you have any solutions or offer for other options, how to check my latex text?
I have found only spell checking in TexWorks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please accept my humble apologies for the sarcastic/humorous comment that follows, and I offer a hearty welcome to the site... Well, first you have to explain the meaning of LaTeX to your Gram-mar (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma) and then she can check it for you.

Comment: A human being is the best spell and grammar checker you can get. No freeware available. You have to pay a human with coffee, beer, chocolate or money for the profesionals.

Answer (score 3):

I use Grammarly and language tool together (They are complements). Just copy and past all of the latex content into them and correct the suggestion and bring back the text. It will work nicely without needing to connect the apps which usually is not working properly (in my case texstudio).

Comment: But these programs also searches only for spelling or article mistake. I want to check tenses and cases. But I guess Grammarly is best what I can get?

Comment: There is also a whitesmoke which is not free and performs better (in compared with each of them). But as I have tried using both Grammarly and language tool can detect almost all defects. The other programs which I don't recommend are ginger and 1checker and several more just google it.

Comment: By the way, the type and versatility of the mistakes they find are way more than the article mistakes. For spellchecking the texstudio Editor usually does a decent work