# Mixed number with slanted fraction

Tags: math-mode, fractions, nicefrac

I wanted to use some mixed numbers with **slanted** fraction in my text, so I used `\sfrac` or `\nicefrac`, [as recommended by S. Kottwitz](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12518).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A not slanted mixed number with \verb|\frac| : \(2\frac{1}{2}\), \(4\frac{3}{7}\)\\
A mixed number with \verb|\sfrac|: \(2\sfrac{1}{2}\), \(4\sfrac{3}{7}\)\\
A mixed number with \verb|\nicefrac|: \(2\nicefrac{1}{2}\), \(4\nicefrac{3}{7}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: appearance of mixed numbers with traditional slanted fraction packages]

But the visual results were not appealing to me. See on the picture how the numerators `1` of `1/2` and `3` of `3/7` look more like the exponents of `2` and `4` respectively. Admittedly, the `\nicefrac` outputs a `nice`r output than `\sfrac`, however not yet satisfying.

How can I improve *the spacing* of the mixed number with the slanted fraction so that the main number and the fraction's numerator look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the spacing in a mixed number, I add the math horizontal spacing `\mspace{<number of mus>mu}` to the mixed number with `\sfrac` (1mu = 1/18em).

My preferred look is adding 1mu extra space between number and slanted fraction, and -3mu extra space between numerator and the slash of the fraction. Thus, I define following command `\mixednumber` for "nicer" mixed numbers:

```
%needs packages 'xfrac' for \sfrac, 'amsmath' for \mspace
\newcommand*{\mixednumber}[3]{\ensuremath{#1\mspace{1mu}\sfrac{#2\mspace{-3mu}}{#3}}}
```

You can adapt the distances by accordingly changing `1mu` or `-3mu` with the preferred spaces. You can even modify the spacing at the denominator by adding the corresponding `\mspace` before the `#3` argument, though, for me, the denominator looks great. ;)

See the minimal example:

[image: appearance of mixed numbers with the \mixednumber command]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

%needs packages 'xfrac' for \sfrac, 'amsmath' for \mspace
\newcommand*{\mixednumber}[3]{\ensuremath{#1\mspace{1mu}\sfrac{#2\mspace{-3mu}}{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A not slanted mixed number with \verb|\frac| : \(2\frac{1}{2}\), \(4\frac{3}{7}\)\\
A mixed number with \verb|\sfrac|: \(2\sfrac{1}{2}\), \(4\sfrac{3}{7}\)\\
A mixed number with \verb|\nicefrac|: \(2\nicefrac{1}{2}\), \(4\nicefrac{3}{7}\)\\
A mixed number with \verb|\mixednumber|: \mixednumber{2}{1}{2}, \mixednumber{4}{3}{7}\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is font feature `+frac` in used font then it is much better to use it instead of to crate a macro which build the fraction from slash and other components. The font designer implements better look of the fraction: suggests better size for numbers and creates (typically) another slant for slash.

Compare following example in Libertine font:

[image: ff]

This example was created by following code in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[libertine]

\def\sfrac#1/#2 {\raise.75ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1\mkern-5mu$}/%
   \lower.35ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern-4mu#2$}}

fontfeature: {\setff{+frac}\rm 2\,1/2}

macro: $2\,\sfrac 1/2 $

\bye
```

Comment: Great! It looks much nicer with this `+frac` feature, sadly it is limited to *ConTeXt* or *OpTeX*. Is that right? Could you provide a translation for standard LaTeX ([the one grandmas use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma) ;))?

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus I don't use LateX but I hope that fontspec package for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX allows to set various font features including +frac. The main problem is if the used font supports such font feature.