# Old LaTeX Template

Tags: fonts, templates, article, letters

I have always liked to read old articles as I find the writing font and symbols very attractive compared to modern templates. Does anyone know what kind of font this is? I would like to make my class notes with this font, but I have not been able to find it.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, the screen shot is from an American Journal of Mathematics article.

Comment: Yes [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373135), but the template used is old I have not been able to get it.

Comment: The received date is 1963, so this is long before electronic capabilities.  It is very likely before the journal in which it was published switched to phototype. Therefore, it was most likely set with Monotype (metal).  If a contemporary Monotype type catalog can be found, that would most likely be the easiest way to match the font.

Comment: @Zaragosa -- This is far too old to have used what is now considered a "template".  The JSTOR image identifies the publisher as Johns Hopkins University Press.  This journal is still in existence (it was founded in 1878).  A polite inquiry to the editorial office might yield the information you are looking for; the journal has a nicely informative web page, although the details of publication practices in 1963 are too obscure to be included there.

Comment: to use the font, you may need one of these: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94891/1090